# Reading data in text file by perl 5

Tags: perl

I want to read this text file which has the following form:

```
0XC@21XAA          c 0000_001 MARRT     AC@21XAA         NERP_111 YYRRT     
                     NBBB_250 MARRT
```

I want to recover in each line, each of the data and to separate by a diese "#" and to put null where the data is empty.
 
Then put it in another file.
 
Do you have an idea

Comment: See also [perldoc perlpacktut](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlpacktut.html)

Answer (score 1):

Here is an example:

```
use feature qw(say);
use strict;
use warnings;

my $fn = 'file.txt';
open ( my $fh, '<', $fn ) or die "Could not open file '$fn': $!";
my $M = 110;
while( my $line = <$fh> ) {
    chomp $line;
    my $N = length $line;
    if ( $N < $M ) {
        my $pad = " " x ( $M - $N );
        $line .= $pad;
    }
    my @fields = unpack "A18xA1xA8xA9xA16xA8xA10xA1xA16xA8xA*", $line;
    @fields = map { length ? $_ : "NULL" } @fields;
    say join "#", @fields;
}    
close $fh;
```

**Output**:

```
0AC@21XAA#A#NAAA_001#MARRT#AC@21XAA#NERP_111#MARRT#NULL#NULL#NULL#NULL
NULL#NULL#NBBB_250#MARRT#NULL#NULL#NULL#A#AC@21XAA#NREP_001#MARRT
0AC@31XAA#A#NCCC_001#MARRT#AC@31XAA#NERP_111#MARRT#NULL#NULL#NULL#NULL
NULL#NULL#NEEE_250#MARRT#NULL#NULL#NULL#A#AC@31XAA#NREP_001#MARRT
0ACACAJAA#A#NFFF_001#MARRT#ACACAJAA#NERP_111#MARRT#NULL#NULL#NULL#NULL
NULL#NULL#NLLL_250#MARRT#NULL#NULL#NULL#A#ACACAJAA#NREP_001#MARRT
NULL#NULL#NULL#NULL#NULL#NULL#NULL#A#ACAC8JAA#NREP_001#MARRT
NULL#NULL#NULL#NULL#NULL#NULL#NULL#A#ACW40JAA#NREP_001#MARRT
```

Comment: Hello,
can you explain to me each of the code and also the agorithm used to have the result. Do I need to import feature modules qw (say);

Comment: @obela06 The algorithm is explained in [`perlpacktut`](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlpacktut.html). Please have a look. You do not need to import modules to use the `say` function, just enable the `say` feature with `use feature qw(say)`

Comment: Haegland thanks a lot. I have another question, how can i export the results in another text file in a specific repository. And Also if i want to add this results to a mysql database how can i modify this perl script

Comment: You are welcome! The simplest way to save the output from the script is to use shell redirection, e.g. `script.pl > file2.txt`. I am not so familar with mysql, so I have to check that out and come back later

Comment: In which position of the script I will add this instruction. Please Can you insert it in the best place in the script ? Or Can you rewrite the complete script to save this data to another text file i will see better

Comment: Yes that `script.pl` is the complete script

Comment: @obela06 This site is not a code writing service. You must put in your own effort and describe what you've tried and explain what's not working.

Comment: @obela06 If you want to insert result into a MySQL database, have a look at [this](https://metacpan.org/pod/DBD::mysql) page